Separate different sets of data in different columns
Basically I have 10 different sets of data (let's say 7000ish rows each) which are in a series of row (in this example I have thus 70000 rows). Basically I am measuring different parameters (y-values) and I would like to plot them against time (x-values). An example of the data would be:
Column 1      Column 2

time 1        temperature 1
time 2        temperature 2
time 3        temperature 3
...           ...
time 1        pressure 1
time 2        pressure 2
time 3        pressure 3
...           ...
time 1        displacement 1
time 2        displacement 2
time 3        displacement 3
...           ...

the data "time 1" of the "temperature 1" measurement is exactly the same as "time 1" of the "pressure 1" and "displacement 1" measurements.
Now what I would like is to express the data in a matrix form:
Column 1      Column 2            Column 3          Column 4            ...

time 1        temperature 1       pressure 1        displacement 1      ...
time 2        temperature 2       pressure 2        displacement 2      ...
time 3        temperature 3       pressure 3        displacement 3      ...
...           ...                 ...               ...                 ...

I am working in Excel, and of course I know I could do it manually with filters and copy-paste, but since I will work with multiple datasets I would like to automate the work as far as I can.

If you have 365, you can use the PIVOTBY function:
Note that I used a Table with structured references, so that you do not need to edit the formula if you add/delete rows/columns
=PIVOTBY(Table2[Column 1],TEXTBEFORE(Table2[Column 2]," "),Table2[Column 2],CONCAT,,0,,0)


If you don't have 365, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let

//Change next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column 1", type text}, {"Column 2", type text}}),

//add a column to Pivot on by removing the sequence from Column 2
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "colHeaders", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column 2]," ")),

//Pivot on this new column
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[colHeaders]), "colHeaders", "Column 2")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

